# Pattern Matcher not accepting parantheses

Tags: java, regex

```
 public class T_token implements Lexer{
        static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\( | \\) | a");
        static Matcher d = p.matcher("( a )");

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          while (d.find()) {
            System.out.println(d.group());
          }
      }
```

When I compile and run this, the output is :

```
run:

 a

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So the input I gave the matcher (variable d) was the string "( a )" but it only prints out a, not the parenthesis left and right brackets.. can someone tell me how i can fix this?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `Pattern` carefully. Literal parentheses must be escaped since unescaped parentheses are metacharacters used for grouping.  I recommend you stop and spend some time learning regular expression syntax and grammar.  There are many resources on the web, as well as the Javadoc.

Comment: What is your actual problem? What do you want to acheive?

Comment: the input i put in is ( a ) and and so i want it to print ( a ), but it ignores the parantheses, i edited my code to have \\( and \\) but it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your regular expression:

1. You added extract spaces such that it will expect space in the pattern to find which doesn't seem to be what you expect.
2. You did not escape the parentheses which are special characters used for grouping. You need to use double backslashes to escape them.

Your regular expression should rather be `\\(|\\)|a`.

**Output:**

```
(
a
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew about \\( and \\) before I put the question but I added the question raw to see if there any other problem, but the actual problem was the backspace like you mentioned and it worked out correctly